# Run function in useeffect when state changes after 1 second if no other changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a searchbar that sends request to my server to give results as the user is writing. It seems a bit impractical to send a request as soon as a user writes if he/she writes quickly, so I would like to make the function in the useEffect hook taking care of this run after 1 second if there has been no input, and reset that timer everytime the user inputs something.

The code works like this at the moment, but I would like to add the functionality described above, but I don't really know how to go about to do that. Does anyone have a solution to this?

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
      if (input.length > 1) {

        (async () => {
          try {
            setLoading(true);
            const res = await axiosget<Searchresult[]>(
              `search/input=${input}`
            );

            setSearchresults(res);
          } catch {
            setSearchResults([]);
          }
          setLoading(false);
        })();
      } else {
        setSearchResults([]);
      }

  }, [input]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a "debounce" function. I would either use one of [many](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) that offer this, or at least abstract [your own implementation](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) into a function that handles debouncing in a generic way.

The idea is that you call the debounce function everytime something changes, but it's implementation only *runs* after the function has not been called in some amount of time.

Then you could do something like:

```
const doSearch = useCallback(
  debounce(async (input: string) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const res = await axios.get<Searchresult[]>(`search/input=${input}`)

      setSearchresults(res)
    } catch {
      setSearchResults([])
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }, 500), // 500ms is the debounce threshold
  [],
)

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (input.length > 1) {
    doSearch()
  } else {
    setSearchResults([])
  }
}, [input, doSearch])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for! I recognize debounce now when I see it, but just didn't think of it when implementing this.